# Python merge items from two rows

Tags: python, type-mismatch

It's ok if I have regular format file, like this:

> Period End Date                 09/30/   06/30/    03/31/   12/31/    09/30/
>
> ```
>              2012  2012  2012  2011  2011
> ```

Then I can merge these dates by zip or `print "%s%s" % (row_1[j], row_2[j])`

But sometimes I have irregular input like this:

> Period End Date               09/30/2012    06/30/    03/31/2011    12/31/    09/30/2012
>
> ```
>                       2011            2010
> ```

or this:

> Period End Date               09/30/    06/30/    03/31/2011    12/31/2011    09/30/2012
>
> ```
>              2012  2011
> ```

So the final date is the merge of row_1 and row2 column, the problem is how dose python know which column it is. How should I approach this?  Appreciate so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do it, with each one generalizing to a different class of inputs-like-this.  How about:

```
def dates_from_two(line1, line2):
    line2 = line2.split()
    for word in line1.split():
        wsplit = word.split('/')
        if len(wsplit) == 3:
            yield word if wsplit[-1] else (word + line2.pop(0))

with open("period.txt") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("Period End Date"):
            next_line = lines[i+1] if i+1 < len(lines) else ''
            dates = list(dates_from_two(line, next_line))
            print dates
```

which gives (for your three cases):

```
['09/30/2012', '06/30/2012', '03/31/2012', '12/31/2011', '09/30/2011']
['09/30/2012', '06/30/2011', '03/31/2011', '12/31/2010', '09/30/2012']
['09/30/2012', '06/30/2011', '03/31/2011', '12/31/2011', '09/30/2012']
```

Basically, the above reads all the lines into memory (not necessary, but simpler if the file isn't too big) and loops over them, looking for lines that start with "Period End Date".  If it finds one, it sends that line and the next to dates_from_two.

dates_from_two simply loops over each word in line1 and tries to split it by `/`.  If that produces three parts, we'll assume it's a date.  If so, then we yield the date if the last part of the date is nonempty, otherwise we yield the sum of the word plus the first term of line2 (which we pop.)  If we never need line2, we never use it.  Note that `line2.pop(0)` means "take the first element of line2 and then delete it".

Comment: Amazing...I am just too fresh to vote up for this answer! Appreciate and learned a lot!

Comment: Question, 

dates = list(dates_from_two(line, next_line))

why you didn't define "return" in dates_from_two() but this function returns word? Because of keyword "yield"??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import sys
import re

f = open("test1_file")
row_1 = f.readline()
row_2 = f.readline()

print row_1,row_2

row_1 = row_1.split()
row_1 = row_1[3:]

row_2 = row_2.split()
row_2.reverse()
r = re.compile(".+/.+/.+")
dates = []
for date in row_1:
    if r.search(date) is None:
        new_date = date+row_2.pop()
        dates.append(new_date)
    else:
        dates.append(date)

print dates
```

You get the following output when you run with one of the sample files given in the question:

```
Period End Date 09/30/2012 06/30/ 03/31/2011 12/31/ 09/30/2012
                            2011            2010

['09/30/2012', '06/30/2011', '03/31/2011', '12/31/2010', '09/30/2012']
```